# Auth0 unable to get ID token / user metadata

Tags: javascript, vue.js, auth0

I am currently working on adding Auth0 to a Vue.js/Node.js application and so far I have figured out how to allow users to register and log in (to /callback) and that seems to be working fine. However, I have manually added (will be automatic later on) some data to the user metadata section. I have the below code as a rule that is turned on. I can’t seem to get access to the data on the Vue.js end of things. What I’d like is to be able to get the user data and user metadata so I can store it in my front end.
Rule code

```
function (user, context, callback) {
  const namespace = 'account_signup_type/';
  const namespace2 = 'account_type';
  context.idToken[namespace + 'is_new'] = (context.stats.loginsCount === 1);
  context.idToken[namespace2] = user.account_type;
  context.idToken.user = user;
  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Code I am trying in my Vue.js front end

```
getIdTokenClaims(o) {
 return this.auth0Client.getIdTokenClaims(o);
}
```

Currently, this returns undefined

Comment: Seems like some `await` is missing. https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/classes/auth0client.html#getidtokenclaims

Comment: @Kunukn Where the code is there is no option to add await. I did make some modifications to allow me to test the idea and it returns the same thing. I am not getting it adding back in. I also tested the rule on Auth0 and it seems I am getting an empty object so the rule code isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out, there was no namespace being created in the id_token which resulted in it not properly passing the data through to the Vue .js app. I added a namespace using a web address format with the domain extension cut off and it now works.

Comment: showing the code after solving would be highly appreciated :)))